# Optimization: Splitting a multidimensional array into subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array consisting of the following format:

```
var source = [['Item 1', 10],['Item 2', 15],['Item 3', 50],['Item 4', 25]];
```

This consists of two parallel datasets: `source[x][0]` which is the data and `source[x][1]` which is the weighting applied to each data item. I find myself in the position of needing to split this into its component arrays, data and weighting. I could (and currently) do this in the following fashion:

```
var weighting = [], data = [];
for (var index = 0; index < source.length; index++)
{
    data.push(source[index][0]);
    weighting.push(source[index][1]);
}
```

Which leads to me having the following two arrays (*continuing from the earlier example*):

```
var data = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4'];
var weighting = [10, 15, 50, 25];
```

Is there a faster way to do this? The source array I am working with contains approximately 2 million sets of data and weighting so something less costly than a loop that splits these apart one entry at a time would represent a significant savings in CPU time.

Comment: Hint: this is called *transposing* a twodimensional array. Looking up that term might lead to better solutions

Comment: Apart from accessing `source[index]` only once, there is nothing you can really do to make this faster. The operation you asked for inherently takes `O(n)` time. If you want actual savings, you will need to optimise your whole algorithm. Tell us why you have arrays of that size in JavaScript, and what you are going to do with them.

Comment: Maybe this isn't helpful because you perhaps can't make the change, but why not avoid creating the multidimensional array in the first place, e.g. creating an array where `source[i]` is a datum and `source[source.length+i]` is its weighting? Then, you could just slice the array into equal halves to get what you want: `source.slice(0, source.length/2)` and `source.slice(source.length/2, source.length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a Code Review question as this solution works and runs correctly. You are mostly interested in performance.

Now it is given that a `for` loop will usually outperform any of the other solutions out there. However you can increase performance a bit.

- Cache the length variable of the array in your loop, prevents having to keep checking the length.
- Retrieve the indexed pair in the loop instead of referencing it twice.

Here is an example:

```
var source = [
  ['Item 1', 10],
  ['Item 2', 15],
  ['Item 3', 50],
  ['Item 4', 25]
];

var data = [],
  weightings = [];

for (var i = 0, l = source.length; i < l; i++) {
  var item = source[i];
  data.push(item[0]);
  weightings.push(item[1])
}

console.log(data);
console.log(weightings);
```

Based on the example in the `for` loop we assign the value of `l` to the length of the array. By `var i = 0, l = source.length;` now this is effectively cached for the duration of the loop.

Next we retrieved the indexed pair (array) in the loop `var item = source[i];` so we don't have to locate it twice within the array.

This can be tested on [jsPerf: Reduce vs. Loop 12](https://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-loop/12).

Now realistically with 2,000,000 records, the orignal method does not take much time (circa 100 ms on my test machine).

Here is a test example check the console the times are pretty close.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51kf3q0o/)

**Performance Review**

Machine (i7 5820k 64 GB DDR4 RAM):
Note I have updated the fiddle to include the `while` version just out of interest.

```
Old Version took 83.56999999999994 ms
Perf Version took 44.24500000000012 ms
While took 76.2800000000002 ms
```

To me that's a *~45%* increase, and yes this is only a small difference in time.

Comment: I can see your point, the optimization here is the difference between 37ms and 43.5ms (using your jsfiddle on my laptop).  This is fairly marginal (though a 15% improvement is not something to sneeze at either), even with the class of dataset I am working with, though depending on how the data is processed (if this code is used for multiple comparably sized but unique datasets) it could add up.

Answer (score 0):

This function just looks at each item in the array and pushes the individual properties into the new arrays. The bottom two loops aren't necessary. I put them there to view the result.

```
var source = [['Item 1', 10],['Item 2', 15],['Item 3', 50],['Item 4', 25]];
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];

splitArray();

function splitArray() {
  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    var item = source[i];
    arr1.push(item[0]);
    arr2.push(item[1]);
  }

  for(var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    console.log(arr1[j]);
  }

  for(var k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
    console.log(arr2[k]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is putting a function wrapper on half of Nico's answer.  Adding the caching of source.length to the splitArray() function and removing the 'result viewing' loops would improve this answer.  Also, if this is to be made more general (as making this into a function instead of a code snippet), then passing in source as a parameter and returning the two arrays might be useful...though returning two arrays as one parameter flies in the face of the function's intent....splitting a two-dimensional array into it's components for separate processing.

Comment: Considering his answer was severely updated after I posted my answer I'm not really concerned about the overlap. I said in my answer the loops could be removed. It was an idea to solve a problem, not a complete solution. Based on the problem statement and the attempted solution, you don't know how to do even this. It was intended as a hint only.

Comment: I'll amend my comment. I didn't even see his answer. There was some other answer there when I started writing that was totally different. Mine and his answers are practically identical. I did not, however, copy his answer.

Comment: @ChrisSharp my original answer was 12 minutes before you, my updates include additional information relevant to the reasons and performance benchmarking. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42684346/1

Comment: If I knew the optimal way to do this, I would have answered my own thread Q&A style as a way of spreading the answer to others.  Attacking me personally does not help.  I merely commented that the older answer already here did a better job of answering the question while suggesting constructive ways to improve your own answer.  If that was taken as a personal attack against you, I apologize as that was not my intent.